# Nodejs: not getting any data while fetching data from MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to fetch data from MongoDB by a field name - `pubdate`, but data is not showing neither I am getting any error!

I have field in **the collection - `_id`, `article`, `headline`, `pubdate`** all are String type except `_id` which is Objectid.

**When I tried this query in Mongo query browser** like - compass and studio 3t I got data -

```json
{ pubdate: { '$gte': '2022-12-01', '$lte': '2022-12-31' } }
```

**I am using postman to fetch data**, in raw option sending POST request in JSON form.

`{"fdate":"2022-12-31","tdate":"2022-12-31"}`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3005;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Connect to MongoDB using Mongoose
const url =
  "mongodb://localhost:2701/db";
mongoose.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

// Define the Article schema
const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  headline: String,
  fulltext: String,
  pubdate: String,
  article_type: String,
});
const Article = mongoose.model("collectioname", articleSchema);

// Route for retrieving articles based on fromdate and todate
app.post("/articles2", (req, res) => {
  let _fDate = req.body.fdate;
  let _tDate = req.body.tdate;

  Article.find({
    pubdate: { $gte: _fDate, $lte: _tDate },
    
  }).exec((err, articles) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send("Error retrieving articles");
      return;
    }
    res.send(articles);
  });
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

How Will I pass the value in Postman to get the record, I am clueless as of now?

**I tried map function too but no output**-

`let _articles = articles.map((x) => x.articleid); res.send(_articles);`

Comment: Are you assuming that by using `collectioname`, Mongoose will use that as the name of the collection it will query? Because it won't. [Read this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection).

Comment: @robertklep thanks for this reference, I did check this and went to this [link](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/schema) where it is doing exactly the same as I did.

Comment: What's the actual collection name (in the database) that you want to query?

Comment: actual name of database is `impact` and collection name is `article_fulltext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is caused by Mongoose, by default, lowercasing and pluralizing the name that you pass when creating the model to determine the name of the collection it will use for the model.

In other words, when you use `mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)`, Mongoose will take the name (`User`) and lowercase and pluralize it, so the collection becomes `users`.

If you want Mongoose to use an *existing* collection, or if you want to have full control of the collection name, you need to use the [`collection`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection) option in your schema:

```
const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  headline: String,
  fulltext: String,
  pubdate: String,
  article_type: String,
}, {
  collection : 'article_fulltext' // the collection to use for this schema
});
const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);
```

Without this option, and assume that you used `article_fulltext` as the model name, Mongoose would have used a collection named `article_fulltexts`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try logging what articles return in exec callback?
One possible issue could be that variables _fDate and _tDate are not seen as Dates by mongoose.So try wrapping them with new Date?

```
Article.find({
pubdate: { $gte: new Date(_fDate), $lte: new Date(_tDate) },
```

})

Comment: I did try this still getting blank, no data, no error! and I did tried to log `articles` I got blank [] value

Comment: @amitkumar Try Setting in mongoose model type to Date instead of String. And also use new Date constructor I suggested

Comment: I did exactly same see - `pubdate: { $gte: new Date(_fDate), $lte: new Date(_tDate) },` andin Schema `pubdate: Date` but still got empty value, why my query is working in Mongodb browser then ?

Comment: @amitkumar Okay, try just find method without any filters. Does it return any collection? Want to identify if issue is with filter only